G has a quaternionic irrep iff G has a central element of order 2?
$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$I just learned an interesting fact (Corollary 23.2 of Representations and Characters of Groups by James and Liebeck): "The group G has a non-trivial real irreducible character if and only if the order of G is even."
So as not to be so specific to finite groups, I think this can be rephrased as "A group G has a non-trivial real irreducible character if and only if G contains an element of order 2."
Anyway, one implication of this fact is that every non-abelian finite simple group has a non-trivial real irreducible character (since every non-cyclic finite simple group has even order by Feit–Thompson theorem).
I checked a number of these real characters in GAP and noticed that for small non-abelian simple groups they all seem to correspond to real representations (i.e. Frobenius-Schur indicator +1) and none correspond to quaternionic/symplectic representations (i.e. Frobenius-Schur indicator -1).
I know that, for any odd prime power $ q $, $ \SL(2,q) $ has FS -1 characters. Is this related to the fact that, for any odd prime power $ q $, $ \SL(2,q) $ has a central element of order 2?
This all leads me to my actual question: Is it true that a group $ G $ has an irreducible character with Frobenius-Schur indicator -1 if and only if $ G $ has a central element of order 2?
Gordon James, and Martin Liebeck. Representations and Characters of Groups. Cambridge University Press, 2001.

The simple group $PSU(3,5)$ has a quaternionic irreducible character, of degree 20.

@DavidA.Craven Ah you're right it looks like $ PSU(3,q) $ for any prime power $ q>2 $ is a simple group whose smallest nontrivial character is quaternionic e.g. $ PSU(3,3) $ of order 6048 is the smallest simple group with all three types of characters. Looks like its my fault from taking too much of my intuition from $ PSL(2,q) $.
